# Preview design in storyboard with class? [objective c]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, class, storyboard

I can do it? Create class file and asign from storyboard then see preview?

[image]

If you have **"YES"** then let me know how can i do this?

Comment: @Chandreah Kachariya what is your point? You want storyboard and class to be shown in parallel? If yes that can even be shown without assigning one.

Comment: @TusharSharma I want preview in storyboard. I already do it but currently I don't remember

Comment: Make a simple Google search , and it will tell you the steps.

Comment: @TusharSharma check below Pratik Jamariya Ans

Comment: @ChandreshKachariya what do you exactly want?

Comment: OP, are you the one downvoting all the answers? Either you don't seem to know what you want or you're not expressing your self clearly. From your question it seems that `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable` are indeed what you need. Just because you don't like an answer doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: I have both are needed (IBDesignable and IBInspectable) to see preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search these two keywords in google, `IBInspectable` and`IBDesignable`.

There are some pretty good tutorials on the internet about these. few links are below:

1. [IBInspectable / IBDesignable Written by Nate Cook](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/)
2. [@IBDesignable and @IBInspectable in Swift 3. by Anantha Krishnan K G](https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-in-swift-3-702d7dd00ca)
3. [What’s IBDesignable / IBInspectable? by Geraldo Bastos](https://medium.com/@GeraldoBastos/whats-ibdesignable-ibinspectable-292829384e1)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might want to live edit your custom views like original UIView, UILabel, UITextField, etc ...
You might want to check  `@IBDesignables` and `@IBInspectables`. 
For Objective-C, these are just `IB_Designable` and `IBInspectable`
If you want to jump right to it, here is the link

https://www.appcoda.com/ibdesignable-ibinspectable-tutorial/